# Dual Boot Ubuntu Windows 10 stuck at loading

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

So i have a msi 16h7 laptop. The specifications are :

https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GS60-6QE-Ghost-Pro.html#hero-overview

I built the usb installer using Rufus and uNetbootin both. I disabled the Secure boot and fast boot.

The installation goes till the point where i get the option of selecting whether to install ubuntu or run it without installing screen. Whatever option i choose, the installation gets stuck at the next screen which is the loading screen with just the Ubuntu and .... being displayed.
Please help with what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with NVIDIA graphics in Ubuntu 15.10 and above. To install, you need to add a special boot flag.

When the GRUB menu comes up, highlight `Try Ubuntu` and press <kbd>E</kbd>. At the end of the line beginning with `linux`, put `nouveau.modeset=0`. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot and install.

After you install, [there are a few other steps you'll want to take to get Ubuntu working.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: I was able to boot ubuntu with this but the driver i could not run. I tried 343,346,361 etc but nothing seemed to work. Everytime i updated the driver i ran into the login loop and had to again purge everything and do it all over again with other drivers. Any solutions?

Comment: Check the other answers. Secure Boot needs to be off. I also have a link at the end of my answer in the other Q&A.